# C++ macro for string literal begin iterator and end iterator

Tags: c++, string, stl, macros

I would like a macro like this

```
STR_ITERATORS("My string")
```

which produces

```
 pBegin, pEnd
```

You could use this to search a vector for example...

`std::vector<char> str1;`

std::search(str1.begin(), str1.end(), STR_ITERATORS("Look for this"));

Note that search takes two pairs of iterators, and the macro provides the second pair.

The macro can be written twice - once for normal chars, once for wide chars.  It doesn't have to solve it all in one.

Note: I don't have the option to use the very latest compilers.  (That makes it a bit boring doesn't it? :-)

Comment: Is this just to save on keystrokes? Why not just make a `search_for_string()` helper function?

Comment: @bluedog: Sure, but macros are frowned upon in C++ for several reasons: 1) It's *very hard* or *impossible* to write a *robust* macro, depending on context, 2) There's no type safety guarantee, 3) Does not respect scope nor namespace rules, 4) There's almost always a superior solution, such as templates and functions.

Comment: Show another example then to make your proposed design viable. You should ask about real life problems you're actually facing. The design you're proposing is inferior to using inline helper functions.

Answer (score 3):

In C++11, making your own search functions for this is easy.

```
template<class iter1, class iter2>
iter1 search(iter1 stackbegin, iter1 stackend, iter2 needlebegin, iter2 needleend)
{return std::search(stackbegin, stackend, needlebegin, needleend);}

template<class iter1, class needlecontainer>
iter1 search(iter1 stackbegin, iter1 stackend, const needlecontainer& needle)
{return std::search(stackbegin, stackend, std::begin(needle), std::end(needle));}

template<class stackcontainer, class needlecontainer>
decltype(std::begin(std::declval<stackcontainer>()))
search(const stackcontainer& stack, const needlecontainer& needle)
{return std::search(std::begin(stack), std::end(stack), std::begin(needle), std::end(needle));}

template<class stackcontainer, class needlecontainer>
decltype(std::begin(std::declval<stackcontainer>()))
search(stackcontainer& stack, const needlecontainer& needle)
{return std::search(std::begin(stack), std::end(stack), std::begin(needle), std::end(needle));}
```

and use them:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<char> str1;
    auto it = search(str1, "Look for this");
}
```

Proof of compilation: http://ideone.com/cO1rz (this version of gcc didn't have `std::begin` and `std::end` so I had to define them myself) and a C++03 version: http://ideone.com/gt1Do

If you really really really want a short macro, and you can *guarantee* that literals share the same space:

```
template<int N>
const char* end(const char(&s)[N]) {return s+N;}
#define STR_ITERATORS(X) X, end(X) //BE WARNED, HIGHLY UNSAFE, NOT PORTABLE
```

Comment: This looks good, but unfortunately my project is across many platforms and some of the compilers are slightly older (but not too old).

Comment: @bluedog: Here's a version that compiles even in older compilers: http://ideone.com/gt1Do

Comment: seems like a good answer, but I was hoping for a more compact, miracle solution.

Comment: @bluedog: Since string literals are not guaranteed to be the same as each other, this is going to be the safest and most compact _portable_ solution.  I can make a macro version, but it would be _more_ code, not less.  It would also be less safe.  or you can ignore portability, and do this easy in Visual Studio.

Comment: it's only the size that's off-putting.  i don't have an issue with templates, and i agree with everyone here that macros are not ideal.  i guess i was just wondering if there was a really short solution to mixing string literals with STL.

Comment: Yeah, I wish it were guaranteed that string literals occupy the same space, but it's not :(

Comment: Two overloads are identical except for the constness of one of the arguments. Is this actually necessary?

Comment: @user833771: Looks are deceiving. They have different return types with different semantics. One returns an `iterator`, and the other returns a  `const_iterator`. So if the caller needs an `iterator`, then they need the first overload, and if the container is `const`, then they need the second overload.

Answer (score 2):

boost range provides overloads of algorithms to use ranges, and will automatically handle most STL-like collections. Specifically, strings can automatically convert to ranges as well. There are also the free functions begin and end.

Comment: This is my favorite answer so far because it's most generally useful.  I wouldn't be able to utilise boost on this project unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

```
template<int N>
int GetLengthOfLiteral(const wchar_t (&literal)[N]) { return N - 1; }

template<int N>
int GetLengthOfLiteral(const char (&literal)[N]) { return N - 1; }

#define LITERAL_ITERATORS(literal) (literal), ((literal) + GetLengthOfLiteral(literal)
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that two different string literals containing the same characters are the same object?

Comment: Which two different string literals?

Comment: `LITERAL_ITERATORS("x")` will expand to `("x"), (("x") + GetLengthOfLiteral("x"))`.  There are three different `"x"`'s in the replacement.  Is it guaranteed that all three of those are the same object?

Comment: Oops, yeah, I forgot about that.